# PHP Typehint question based of certification preparation

Tags: php, type-hinting

I am going through a certlab exam question for a PHP certification. They asked the following question and I do not understand why the answer is 'A'.

**Which of the following statements is NOT correct?**

```
A. Only methods can have type hints
B. Typehints can be optional
C. Typehints can be references
```

In my opinion :

- A : is correct [edit : unless they meant you typehint the actual method, whereas I interpreted it as using typehints in the parameter and return statement.]
- B : is correct
- C : is wrong. How do you add a
  reference to a typehint? Sure you can reference the variable that is
  typehinted but not the typehint?

Comment: A - Peter's note below is better for A. B is correct, I feel C implies you can type hint a reference which is true. It could easily have been better worded admittedly.

Comment: Functions can have type hints too.

Comment: Can you ask them about the definition of "optional"?

Comment: Thanks, @Peter I should have differentiated between methods and functions but I did not. Jon Sterling I also think that C was not worded as good as it could get. I will accept Peter's answer because it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Peter, I believe the correct answer is that functions can also be typehinted. There is a "difference" between methods and functions, although I believe the difference is more conceptual than actual.